# Change version number in launchpad

Tags: quickly, packaging, launchpad, bazaar

While committing package to launchpad through quickly submit, version automatically jumped to current month, that is 12.07. I did try to delete all milestones and re-upload the package. But every time, launchpad is rejecting submission due to "Version older than that in the archive". How to fix this ?

Comment: Are you Re-Uploading the **SAME** package without any changes.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot upload a version older or equal to, a version you've already uploaded to a PPA. My advice would be to live with the mistake, and don't make the same mistake in the future. Be sure everything is right, before you upload something to a PPA.

You can use sbuild or pbuilder to run test builds locally in a chroot, to help ensure everything builds properly, before uploading.

Comment: Who downvoted this 6 year old answer? And why? Launchpad keeps version history in the database and you cannot upload a version older or equal to, what you have already uploaded (because if someone installed the newer version, they won't know they need to force a downgrade manually).

Comment: Sorry, that's mine: advice not to make mistakes in a future looks redundant for me.